# How to understand apt.log?

Tags: apt, upgrade, python, package-management

First, a little context:
I have a machine with Ubuntu 13.10 64bit with Unity, that i use for development.
As such, i updated several packages manually, and even installed/compiled some from sources (e.g. python3 - 3.4.0).

Now, as i am trying to upgrade to 14.04 i get the error "Cannot calculate the upgrade". From what i read online, this is a specific issue on each machine, no "miracle solution exists". So i started reading `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` to see what packages are Broken to try and fix them.

The question is: How do i interpret the line?

```
Broken python3-dbus:amd64 Depends on python3 [ amd64 ] < 3.3.2-14ubuntu1 -> 3.4.0-0ubuntu2 > ( python ) (< 3.4)
```

Does this mean i have 3.3.2.14 updated to 3.4.0 and it expects version less than (<) 3.4?
Or the other way around?

Btw, I have reinstalled python3, **`dpkg -l` shows 3.3.2-14, but python3 binary shows version 3.4.0**

Thanks.

Comment: run `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix the broken packages.

Comment: sudo apt-get install -f
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Please note i'm trying to upgrade, the apt.log is for dist-upgrade.
The packages on system are all ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the interpretation, that line means that the package `python3-dbus:amd64` (at whatever version it is set to be, Saucy's or Trusty's) depends on `python3`, whose version has to be `< 3.4`.

However, that doesn't make sense to me because `python3-dbus` on Trusty needs `python3` to be `>= 3.4~`, so I'm assuming that constraint is coming from the current Ubuntu version you're running (which is probably Saucy).

Also, note that since you compiled `python3` from sources and haven't installed it through dpkg/apt, nor have you used a PPA, it's not recognized or seen by the upgrade manager, and `dpkg -l` will report it as the version you installed from the repos.

Comment: Indeed, it's Saucy, and indeed dpkg -l shows python3 as 3.3.1. But i think that files have been overwritten so python3 cannot be updated automatically, i'll dig some more.
For now i'll accept this answer, thanks.

Comment: Overwritten files are a bit of a problem, but it doesn't affect the apt.log. In other words, `dpkg` keeps its own database of the packages installed and version number (and other things), so you could delete many applications and libraries, but `dpkg` will think that those are installed.